# Warning in every model of glmmTMB 'giveCsparse'

Tags: r, warnings, glmmtmb

I am using the glmmTMB library to run mixed models, within a R markdown document. Any model that I run, I get these warnings:

```
'giveCsparse' has been deprecated; setting 'repr = "T"' for you'giveCsparse' has been deprecated; setting 'repr = "T"' for you'giveCsparse' has been deprecated; setting 'repr = "T"' for you
```

Then, if I run the code in the console, I get these warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In Matrix::sparseMatrix(dims = c(0, 0), i = integer(0), j = integer(0),  :
  'giveCsparse' has been deprecated; setting 'repr = "T"' for you
2: In Matrix::sparseMatrix(dims = c(0, 0), i = integer(0), j = integer(0),  :
  'giveCsparse' has been deprecated; setting 'repr = "T"' for you
3: In Matrix::sparseMatrix(dims = c(0, 0), i = integer(0), j = integer(0),  :
  'giveCsparse' has been deprecated; setting 'repr = "T"' for you
```

My code looks like this:

```
m1 <- glmmTMB(count~var1+var2+var3+(1|group), data = bd, family = "poisson")
```

I tried reinstalling TMB and glmmTMB with `dependencies=TRUE`, but the message keeps appearing. Apparently it doesn't affect the model at all, but whatever tests or graphs I do, I keep getting warnings. Is it possible to fix this? Or do I just ignore it?

Comment: I've updated the package repositories.  Can someone on Windows or MacOS try `install.packages("glmmTMB", repos="https://glmmTMB.github.io/glmmTMB/repos")` and see if it resolves this problem (so I can edit #3 in my answer to take out the cautionary note) ?

Comment: I tried it with different mixed models. It works ok, the warning no longer appears.

Comment: great ..........

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's harmless. You can:

1. Install the latest version of `glmmTMB` (1.1.2 at present) from CRAN.
2. ignore it
3. use `suppressWarnings()` (at the possible cost of missing other relevant warnings!)
4. [install the development version from GitHub](http://glmmtmb.github.io/glmmTMB/), where it was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/commit/0f14b450fd071dcd85d6d53c0c1148a316b70234). (The binary packages on the repository have also been updated now.)

or you could *downgrade* your version of `Matrix` to an older version (using `remotes::install_version()` or the `snapshot` package)